# How to copy and duplicate a Drawing with a Script attached

Tags: google-sheets

I created a drawing and added a script to it in a Google Sheet tab. My sheet has 20 tabs. How can I copy and paste or otherwise duplicate the Drawing with its script onto each of the other 19 tabs?

Comment: It's annoying that you can't copy a drawing using CTRC+C direct to Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

that is kind of unachievable at this age. best you can do is:

- enter drawing mode of your drawing
- select it
- copy it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- then go to Sheet2
- insert new drawing
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
- then go to Sheet3
- insert new drawing
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
- etc... 17x
- and then assign your script function to every drwing on every sheet